# Could not find SYSTEM.BROKER service with WebSphere MQ v7.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq

I'm new trying to configure MQ service [following this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0610_woolf/0610_woolf.html) but when I tried to alter the service `SYSTEM.BROKER` it says that it cannot be found. What possibly am I doing wrong?

I'm using Version 7.0 of WebSphere MQ.

Comment: You'll probably need to provide more details.

Comment: @DaveNewton Not when T.Rob answers a WMQ question ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the article applies to WMQ v6.0 whereas in v7.0 there is no pub/sub broker.  In v7.0 and higher, pub/sub is natively supported as part of the queue manager.

After a quick review of the tutorial, I believe that you can safely skip all of *Step C: Set Up Pub/Sub*.  This step creates the queues that the V6 pub/sub broker required and then started it.  V7 neither requires these queues nor has a separate pub/sub broker component to start.

You can actually see this in action in the last 45 seconds or so of [this video](http://youtu.be/wSCHLBftjDw) where a new QMgr is created and then, without any additional setup, a message is published and received with a subscriber.

So skip Step C and continue on with the tutorial and you should be OK.